# Why are packages suddenly greyed out in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have been working on an inherited webapp project and a few hours ago I exported to war file. I imported from the war file on another system (Ubuntu) and noticed all the project's packages are greyed out. Some I can expand others I can't.
Deploying the project in a container works fine, and does show the updates I made, however I can't get at the packages, or files I edited.

I have researched online and gotten no closer to an answer so far.
Any reason as to what's happening? I use Eclipse 3.7 on both systems.

Comment: Have you tried unpacking the WAR file and importing it as regular source code?

Comment: I will try that but I would still like to know why this happened in the first place. It's a huge project and can't keep doing this all the time if it happens again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A war file only contains compiled classes. You won't find your source files in a war file. That's not what it's used for.

If you want to share code and project files between two machines, use SVN, Git or another version control system. Even with 1 machine, you should use it anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Any way to regenerate my src files from the war file?

Comment: Why would you do that? Did you delete the original project sources? You may try to decompile the classes, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: I must've have forgotten to tick the import source files when I exported so the source files are missing from the war

Comment: I'm trying to. I just installed the JD-Eclipse decompiler but I can't find the option to use it. I've never had to decompile a Java project until now :)

Comment: Why can't you just zip the original project, with the sources, transfer this sip, and import the eclipse project on your Ubuntu server?

Comment: I inherited it. I'm getting round to setting up a git server but for now I'm tasked with implementing a few quick features. unfortunately I need to reverse engineer the source files at the moment as my laptop is in the shop.